# PHP script error when value is zero

Tags: php

I not understand little bit. Simple switch statement not working correctly with zero value (`=0`):

```
//$result = $sql->fetchColumn(); 
$result = 1;
      switch ($result) {    
          case $result <= 2 :
              throw new Exception('Error!');
              break;
                        }
```

Problem is when `$result = 0` then output should be 'error' but in this case script passing this validation. Weird question but i can't find a problem.

Comment: A normal **IF** statement should be your friend in that case

Comment: This is just a fragment of the code. I need to find out why that's happens

Comment: You haven't understand how switch statement works. You can't execute a "greater than... less than" etc. in a switch statement. You can only do a case for a specific number. http://us2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Ok i understand now

Comment: I've posted an answer that shows you how you can do it with a switch-statement. :) Hope you'll find your solution. If you need more help, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it like that:

```
<?php
switch ($i) {
case 0:
case 1:
case 2:
    throw new Exception('Error!');
    break;
case 3:
    echo "i is 3 or higher.";
}
?>
```

As I said in my comment above, you can't use "grater than" "less than" etc. in a switch-statement. As other said, if you want to make use of them, use a simple `IF` statement.

Answer (score 0):

this code

```
switch ($result) {    
      case $result <= 2 :
```

is equivalent

```
if($result == ($result <= 2))
```

and when

```
$result=0
```

we have

```
( 0 == true )
```

after type conversion

```
false === true
```

and this is false as expected